# Any way can association variables in different functions at scrapy

Tags: python, scrapy

I using scrapy(ver:1.1.1) to scrapy something, but I don't know how to association variables in different functions, can anybody help me?

```
import os
import sys
reload(sys)
sys.setdefaultencoding("utf-8")

import codecs
import scrapy

class LinkSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'go'
    allowed_domains = ['example_0.com']

def start_requests(self):
    with codecs.open('go.txt', 'r', 'utf-8') as f:
        start_urls = [url.strip() for url in f.readlines()]
    for start_url in start_urls:
        yield scrapy.Request(start_url, callback=self.parse_handle302, meta={'dont_redirect': True, 'handle_httpstatus_list': [302]})

def parse_handle302(self, response):
    product = {}
    r = re.compile(r'\d+')
    i = response.request.url
    tid = r.findall(i)
    yield scrapy.Request(i, callback=self.parse_handle301, dont_filter=True)

def parse_handle301(self, response):
    link = response.request.url
    print '\n'

    product['tid'] = tid
    product['link'] = link

    print product
```

When I run scrapy, it told me:

```
NameError: global name 'tid' is not defined
```

So, How can I association the 'tid' and 'link'，every ‘tid’ mapping itself ‘link’, after the 'start_url' in 'start_urls' via redirect 302 and 301?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe [this(passing additional data to callback functions)](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html?highlight=Request.meta#passing-additional-data-to-callback-functions) is what you want.